# How can I set/use the input in the JTextField as the name of the table that will be created in the database?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, xampp

I'm still new to jdbc but I was able to create a new table in the database by clicking the JButton, its code is commented out. But what I need to do is take the user's input in the Jtextfield and set it as the table's name that will be created in the database. Need help pls.

```
NameT = new JTextField();
JButton SaveB = new JButton("Save");
SaveB.setFocusable(false);
SaveB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample","root","");
           String input = NameT.getText();
        // String sql="CREATE TABLE sample.English AS SELECT * FROM subject;"; 
           String sql="CREATE TABLE sample.'"+input+"' AS SELECT * FROM subject;"; 
           PreparedStatement ptst = conn.prepareStatement(sql); ptst.executeUpdate(); 
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data stored successfully");
            conn.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not stored successfully");
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what isn't working?

Comment: It cannot take the input on the JTextField and set it as a name for the new table in the database. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Did you display the created SQL string to verify the format? It looks to me like you are adding delimiters around the table name.

Comment: I have also tried it but the connection with the database always fails.

Comment: // String input = NameT.getText();
     String sql="CREATE TABLE sample.English AS SELECT * FROM subject;"; 
 // String sql="CREATE TABLE sample.'"+input+"' AS SELECT * FROM subject;"; 

But if I commented out the sample that does takes input and set as a name for the new  table, the connection with the database is successful.